# Which StackExchange website is the best for general non-programming Linux questions?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Which StackExchange website is the best for general non-programming Linux questions? I have some Linux questions that are not directly related to Ubuntu and not related to programming. Does StackExchange have a site for this? Here is a specific example of my issue: [What are some of these directories in the Linux kernel src?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304880/what-are-some-of-these-directories-in-the-linux-kernel-src)

Comment: Your question is ontopic here, I don't know why it was voted offtopic, I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, thank you very much. I was starting to get confused about what was on topic.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I agree with Devyn; it _is_ confusing whether this is on topic, and I get the impression that not everyone is in agreement when reviewing and moderating questions. I have just had a comment deleted because I suggested that a question would be better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/, which I personally think is going too far given that many general Linux questions might get better answers elsewhere.

Comment: It's not confusing that this is ontopic, if you use Ubuntu it's ontopic here. If people tell you that something is offtopic but the user is using Ubuntu then that is incorrect.

Comment: @JorgeCastro The Ask a Question page says "Is your question about Ubuntu?" not "Are you using Ubuntu?". This distinction might not seem confusing to you, but it is to me; the word "about" is not clearly defined, in my opinion, even in the FAQs. If you are referring to my deleted comment, I feel the need to point out that it did not state that the question was offtopic, it just suggested that it might be better asked elsewhere. I still think that is helpful advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) should be exactly what you are looking for.

From the site's [description page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/about):

> **Unix & Linux Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Unix or Linux.

Comment: +1, while it's possible to argue that the question is on-topic here, it's a generic Linux question and if I had the same question, I'd ask it at unix.se.

Comment: @Glutanimate, thank you. I am going to love your suggested site!

Comment: @Glutanimate, I have been using Unix.StackExchange a lot ever since you suggested it. Thanks!

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson : You're welcome. Glad to see my answer helped :)