# Are questions about the finer points of the linux kernel on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My question is in regards to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540665/packet-traversal-through-ubuntu-kernel

This is a question about the nitty-gritty underpinnings of the linux kernel. While, technically, related to Ubuntu it's not really Ubuntu-specific. [this question on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6841/which-stackexchange-website-is-the-best-for-general-non-programming-linux-questi) leads me to think the proper place is  not here but on unix.se instead.

Comment: Sounds like that guy really needs a forum for a discussion, not a Q/A site.

Comment: Related: A Google search for "kernel stack exchange" brings up the `linux-kernel` tags for [unix.se] and [so]. AU isn't anywhere *near* the top set of results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A whole ton of things that are roughly related to the Ubuntu project (including software it includes and development on it) are explicitly on-topic here. Your [example meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6841/which-stackexchange-website-is-the-best-for-general-non-programming-linux-questi) is looking for the *best* place for generic questions. That's quite a different question than asking if something is on-topic or not.

The question is quite broad though. It wants a blow-by-blow of Linux networking; something you'd usually suggest somebody read a book or two about. It is *probably* answerable at a high level by somebody who *really* knows their Kernel networking.

Short answer, it's probably on topic but possibly not the best fit for the Q&A format. I'm perfectly happy to let time sort this out.