# How to choose StackExchange site for a linux question

Tags: discussion

I'm troubleshooting various issues with my Ubuntu system.  I've been asking them in the **Ask Ubuntu** forum, but they haven't been getting a lot of attention.  That could easily be my fault for various reasons, but I wonder if I might have more success (due to more exposure to a larger audience) posting them on the **Unix and Linux** site or the **Super User** site.

What's the decision tree people should use?  If the question's scope applies to non-Ubuntu distributions, does it belong to the **Unix and Linux** site?  I'd venture to say that the majority of questions asked in **Ask Ubuntu** also apply to other distributions.

This is a more generalized version of [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6841/which-stackexchange-website-is-the-best-for-general-non-programming-linux-questi).

Per Jorge Castro's suggestion, here are links to the two questions that got me thinking about this:
[Airplay sink no longer visible in pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544251/troubleshooting-airplay-pulseaudio)

["Failed to open audio output" error when trying to send audio from mpd to pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544925/troubleshooting-pulseaudio-and-mpd)

However I'm asking *this* question in a more general context.

Comment: Can you also link to your question so we can check it out?

Comment: @JorgeCastro thanks for the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

AU gets more traffic than U&L<strike>, I think</strike><sup>1</sup>, but I'd say the major cause of your problems not getting attention are that they're in tough areas. I see `pulseaudio` in a question, I tend to mentally block it. I have fought my battles with it and lost spectacularly.

> If the question's scope applies to non-Ubuntu distributions, does it belong to the Unix and Linux site?

Not necessarily. If at least one of the platforms actually involved in the question is Ubuntu, and it does involve the OS in some way, you could make a case for it being on-topic here. There are exceptions. For example, if you have dual-booted Ubuntu and Mint, and want to get something on Mint working, that is off-topic here.

You could try asking elsewhere, but if you do, remember to delete your questions here. Cross-posting on multiple SE sites is not welcome.

<sub><sup>1</sup> We do get more traffic: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

About 400k visits per day for AU as opposed to 168k for U&L. SU has a higher rate at 640k+/day and better answer rate (72% vs 66%). U&L has a much higher answer rate (82%), but IMO they, like SF, are stricter on question quality (not a problem in your case, I'd think). You could try on SU, but I'd think the experts on Linux are either here or on U&L (probably both, as I have seen a lot of familiar usernames in U&L in my brief forays there).</sub>

Comment: Flagging for migration could also be more efficient than deleting and re-asking, if the OP wants. Just remember to specify the target site in the flag!

Comment: Yes, the pulseaudio tag is something of a poison pill.  I'll probably have more success on a pulseaudio site/mailing list.  I just always go to the stack exchange sites first - they work so incredibly well once they reach critical mass...

Comment: @FredHamilton if you do end up going to a mailing list, could you come back and add an answer here if you get a solution?

Comment: Absolutely (as long as I can figure out what I did to fix it).

Comment: But UL answer questions faster ([49 hours](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/226962/site-question-stats) vs [40 on unix](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/226962/site-question-stats)) and has [more eyes after you submit your question in the first months of life.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16906647#16906647)